# Object Debugger Error Scraping Page ... near solution?

Tags: facebook, screen-scraping

I have a very strange issue while sharing a page, probably connected to DNS used by Facebook.

I usually share pages from my own sites with no problem. In only one new site, I cannot correctly share any page.

where is the problem?

If I try to share a page from this new site (www.tarocchibluemoon.com), I expected to share an image, a page title etc.

However, I didn't see any images choosen from the ones in my page.

I used the debugger `developers.facebook.com/tools/debug`

and typed in the site http://www.tarocchibluemoon.com having a beautiful `"Critical Errors must be fixed"`

Looking deeper in Graph API I see:

```
{
   "url": "http://www.tarocchibluemoon.com/",
   "type": "website",
   "title": "www.tarocchibluemoon.com",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://www.tarocchibluemoon.com/images/domain_reserviert.gif"
      }
   ],
   "updated_time": "2011-11-14T20:43:22+0000",
   "id": "10150336639081017"
}
```

This means that debugger sees the site like it was a month ago when the provider showed the classic default page shown when you buy a new domain with written inside "The domain is reserved" (a page like this [example](http://www.realizzazionesitisansepolcro.it)).

Probably Facebook didn't received the update to the DNS done when I published the site!

I tried also to change again the IP address of my site but with no results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the canonical tag in your head section (end of line 3):

```
<link href="http://bluemoon.thiellaconsulting.com/Default.aspx" rel="canonical" />
```

Facebook tries to scrape your canonical url - but in this case that url doesn't exist so you get a 'can't download' error.

If you switch that tag so it points to your current domain (or remove it altogether) you should allow Facebook to scrape the page and update it's graph entry.